# log4j vulnerability with avro-tools-1.9.1.jar

Tags: java, security, log4j, avro-tools

Apache avro scanning shows the log4j vulnerability.
How to get rid of it?
Tried with:

java -jar target/log4j-detector-latest.jar /c/workspace/sampleApp

-- github.com/mergebase/log4j-detector v2021.12.29 (by mergebase.com) analyzing paths (could take a while).
-- Note: specify the '--verbose' flag to have every file examined printed to STDERR.
C:\workspace\sampleApp\target\SampleApp\WEB-INF\lib\avro-tools-1.9.1.jar contains Log4J-1.x   <= 1.2.17 *OLD*

I have tried to upgrade to avro-tools version 1.11.0 that too shows the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the JAR file and delete the following files that belong to log4j 1.x within the JAR file to mitigate the vulnerabilities. They are present in the folder `/org/apache/log4j/net/` within the JAR:

- `JMSAppender.class`
- `SocketServer.class`
- `SocketAppender.class`
- `SMTPAppender.class`
- `SMTPAppender$1.class`

Once deleted these classes can no longer be used by a log4j logging configuration (which is the way to trigger the vulnerabilities).

If the application does not work after the modification it needs to be migrated to use a newer log4j 2.x version: Log4j 2.3.2 (for Java 6), 2.12.4 (for Java 7), or 2.17.1 (for Java 8 and later)) - see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/